# Data warehouse and/or database?

Tags: database, data-warehouse

Can an enterprise use both data warehouse and database in one Head Office?  Is it just OK to use only one of these or is it necessary to  use both in the same place?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, an enterprise can use both data warehouse and database in one office. They need not be in the same physical data-center. It all depends on the needs of the organization. Generally, databases are used to support transactions as they happen and data warehouses are used to support business intelligence or the like.

**Database**

Transactions in an enterprise is most likely to happen in a relational database management system (aka database, aka RDBMS). Reporting can happen using the same database, but it is also possible that reporting is done off of a mirror of the RDBMS. Now, an enterprise may have more than one RDBMS - one running SQL Server, one running Oracle, one running MySQL etc. All this is great for recording activities and reporting.

**Warehouse**

Additionally, enterprises seek to do data analysis on a regular basis. Business Intelligence, data science, big data - regardless of the term, we are talking about data analysis overall. Doing number crunching on large amounts of data stored in an RDBMS can be hard on the RDBMS. So, organizations decide to de-normalize data to some extent and store data in a warehouse. When data is extracted, transformed and loaded (ETL) from one or more RDBMS (and other sources of data) and stored in a data warehouse, it is available for some research.

Organizations may choose to move the warehouse to a different office location, or may have multiple-warehouses. For example, a headquarter with 5 satellite facilities may choose to bring data from all those facilities to the warehouse at the headquarter every night, or it may choose to have a warehouse in a different datacenter. In contrast to that, a company with hundreds of satellite facilities may choose to have a warehouse with high-level summarized data at their headquarter and regionalize their warehouses; one warehouse in each continent, so that target markets are better served by satellite units in that particular continent.

Database (or databases) to Warehouse journey
[image: Warehousing]

**Business Intelligence**

Cognos, QlikView, Tableau, Microstrategy etc. are some business intelligence/data analytic tools among many that reach out to the data warehouse and present data for analytics. They are great for presentation and reporting - data visualization, in general. These tools can also get data from RDBMS, but it's convenient to get it from data warehouse since they are architected in a way to make it easier to showcase that data on a business intelligence dashboard

Example of a dashboard:
[image: Dashboard example]

**Big data**

The buzzword around big data is interesting. Many of us may take a subset of data from a large pool of data, do analysis and assume that the results from the subset applies to the large pool of data. What if all the data was used for analysis? And even better - what if we took related data from elsewhere (outside of our dataset) and included it in our analysis? Yeah, you would have a giant pile of data and if you had means to analyze them all, you'd be doing big data. We are talking several hundred GB or even PB of data. Although Hadoop and the like are used in big data analysis, they could derive that data from the warehouse.